# EEXIST error when trying to overwrite an existing file in Gulp?

Tags: gulp

I have a few tasks in my Gulpfile that I would like to run and either have their output replace or alter an existing file.  For example, I want to run `wiredep`  and have code replace the blocks inside `index.html` (which is the same file as the source) so basically I have the have the following:

```
gulp.task('bower', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/index.html')
    .pipe(wiredep())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/index.html')) // Have wiredep operate on the source 
})
```

But this creates an `EEXIST` error.

Similarly, I would like to run the `stylus` command, and pipe the output to a file that already exists (because it was previously run).

Do I have any choise but to run `del` each time?  It seems like Gulp should be able to easily overwrite existing files but I can't figure out a simple way.

Comment: Gulp always overwrites existing files. `EEXIST` errors are usually a sign that you're not handling some asynchronous operation correctly.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung This seems like a pretty simple task, do you see anything I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`gulp.dest()` expects a **directory**. You're passing it a **file name**.

What happens is that gulp tries to create the directory `app/index.html`, which it can't since there's already a file with that name.

All you need to do is pass `app/` as the destination directory:

```
gulp.task('bower', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/index.html')
    .pipe(wiredep())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'));
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `gulp.dest` which has an option [`overwrite`](https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpdestpath-options#section-options-overwrite)

> `options.overwrite`
>   Type: Boolean
>
> Default: true
>
> Specify if existing files with the same path should be overwritten or not.

Comment: It looks like that defaults to `true`, but it is not working?

Comment: @Startec but where are you calling `gulp.dest`?

Comment: I just updated the question.  I am calling it on the end and want to operate on the same file

Comment: I believe @SvenSchoenung addresses the issue but yeah `dest` expects a directory and not a specific file name.

Answer (score 2):

It will be ok.

```js
gulp.task('bower', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/index.html')
    .pipe(wiredep())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app')) // Have wiredep operate on the source 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Gulp have `overwrite` option

```
gulp.task('bower', () => {
  return gulp.src('input/*.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('output/',{overwrite:true})) 
})
```

another example

```
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');

function copy() {
  return src('input/*.js')
    .pipe(dest('output/',{overwrite:true}));
}
```

full documentation https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/dest